# Running vcbuildtools.bat in PowerShell on startup in cmder

Tags: powershell, conemu, cmder

Usage of the command prompt is disabled here, so when I want to use the Visual C++ Build Tools (i.e. enable the usage of `cl`), I have to use PowerShell. I use the following line, which works fine:

```
cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools\vcbuildtools.bat" x86_amd64 `& powershell
```

However, I want to try and run this command automatically whenever I try to start up cmder. I have this line specified in the 'Command line' area of the startup settings, but it gives the following error:

```
Error in script usage. The correct usage is:
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools\vcbuildtools.bat" [option]
where [option] is: x86 | amd64 | x86_amd64 | x86_arm | amd64_x86 | amd64_arm
ECHO is off.
For example:
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools\vcbuildtools.bat" x86_amd64
```

What do I need to change in the line to get it to work?

Comment: Why have you got a backtick before the `&`?

Comment: Oh, thank you! I had the backtick when I was running the script from PowerShell itself because the `&` needed to be escaped, but I forgot that cmder wasn't running it from PowerShell to begin with. Problem (indirectly) solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What do I need to change in the line to get it to work?

```
cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools\vcbuildtools.bat" x86_amd64 `& powershell
```

Remove the backtick `` ` `` from `` `& ``.

The `` ` `` escapes the `&` so the reset of the line gets passed as parameters to `vcbuildtools` instead of being interpreted by `cmd`.